# Help in understanding a proof in Rudin's Principles of Mathematical analysis

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Hi I was reading Rudin's Princiaples of MathematicalA Analysis. In the third chapter in tying to prove

If $\{p_n\}$ is a sequence in a metric space $X$ and if $\{p_n\}$ converges $\implies$ $\{p_n\}$ is bounded

The proof goes as follows
Suppose $p_n \rightarrow p$. There is an integer $N$ such that $\forall n>N \implies d(p_n,p)<1$

Now if we put $r=max\{1,d(p_1,p),d(p_2,p),.....,d(p_N,p)\}$

This implies $d(p_n,p)\leq r  \forall n\in N $

Why can't say $d(p_1,p)$ be infinite which makes r infinite and therefore $\{p_n\}$ unbounded?

Comment: In a metric space the distance $d$ is a mapping $d \colon X \times X \to \mathbb{R}$ and infinity is not a real number, so there are no "infinite" distances.

Comment: Yes ofcourse , my bad! Thank you J.J

Answer (score 2):

The definition of a metric space requires that the distances are real numbers. Infinity is not a real number, so $d(p_1,p)$ cannot be $\infty$.

There are generalizations of metric spaces where we allow infinite distances, but that's a different story.